# Standalone example on jberet (jsr352)

Tags: jboss, batch-processing, spring-batch, wildfly-8

Is there anyway to use jberet as standalone module to execute Batch Jobs?

All the time getting samples on using along with WildFly.

Surprised to see it looks for container to load implementations while trying some samples.

Any insights on why/why not would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tutorial how to use jberet in a standalone application:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/batch-api/running-batch-jobs-in-j2se-applications

You'll need to include various jboss dependencies for it to work.
Furthermore you need to configure jberet with a separate jberet.properties.

I've build a (hopefully) minimal example application according to the tutorial.
You can find it here: https://github.com/kaape/jberet-standalone-example

More information can be found in the jberet github repository:
https://github.com/jberet

Comment: @NageswaraRao I've build an example application and put the github repository link in my answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify/replace custom extension of  org.jberet.spi.BatchEnvironment at jberet-se?

Comment: @kaape   Is jberet implementation optimized for running production batch jobs ? I am looking for an alternative other than a JEE Container to run java batch jobs. Our target environment will be mainframes (z/OS).

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar example but uses JDBC chunk oriented processing. https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/jberet-se-example

Comment: i am getting exceptions when trying to run jberet in standalone Java SE mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520574/jsr352-jberet-error-while-running-sleepybatchlet-using-jberet  could you please help

Answer (score 0):

JBeret project test-apps sub-module (https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/tree/master/test-apps) contains various test apps that are structured as standalone Java SE applications (except restAPI where WildFly appserver is needed).

For JBeret + WildFly samples, please check out JBeret project wildfly-jberet-samples module:

https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/tree/master/wildfly-jberet-samples

Comment: i am getting exceptions when trying to run jberet in standalone Java SE mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520574/jsr352-jberet-error-while-running-sleepybatchlet-using-jberet  could you please help