# Using jbatch in J2SE applications

Tags: batch-processing, java-ee-7

Can I use [jbatch](https://java.net/projects/jbatch/) in J2SE applications (without application server)? Is there any example? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using jberet (https://github.com/jberet), as an alternative implementation of the JSR 352, you'll find links to resources and a standalone example here: [Standalone example on jberet (jsr352)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734863/standalone-example-on-jberet-jsr352)

Comment: I have been getting exceptions when trying to use jberet in standalone Java SE mode   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520574/jsr352-jberet-error-while-running-sleepybatchlet-using-jberet